Making database (PostgreSQL) with Python, data is loaded from Excel, some rows are not in the right spot
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

DB_NAME = "Test"
DB_USER = "*********"
DB_PASSWORD = "j*********"
DB_HOST = "localhost"
DB_PORT = "5432"

engine = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}')

excel_file_path = 'C:\\.....'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)

columns = ['Name_of_the_file', 'Name_of_sheet', 'Item_code', 'tbd', 'tbd1', 'tbd2', 'Item_07', 'Item_08', 'Item_09', 'Item_10', 'Qty', 'Unit', 'Datum']
data = []


current_name_of_sheet = None
current_item_07 = None
current_item_08 = None
current_item_09 = None
Name_of_the_file = 'BoQ Building Services-Base'

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    A_value = row['A']
    B_value = row['B']
    C_value = row['C']
    D_value = row['D']
    E_value = row['E']
    if B_value == 2:
        current_name_of_sheet = D_value
        current_item_08 = None
        current_item_09 = None
        current_item_07 = None

        data.append([Name_of_the_file, current_name_of_sheet, A_value, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None])
    elif B_value == 7:
        current_item_07 = D_value
        data.append([Name_of_the_file, current_name_of_sheet, A_value, None, None, None, current_item_07, None, None, None, None, None, None])
    elif B_value == 8:
        current_item_08 = D_value
        data.append([Name_of_the_file, current_name_of_sheet, A_value, None, None, None, None, current_item_08, None, None, None, None, None])
    elif B_value == 9:
        current_item_09 = D_value
        data.append([Name_of_the_file, current_name_of_sheet, A_value, None, None, None, None, None, current_item_09, None, None, None, None])
    elif B_value == 10:
        data.append([Name_of_the_file, current_name_of_sheet, A_value, None, None, None, None, None, None, D_value, E_value, C_value, None])

df_to_insert = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

table_name = 'table3'
df_to_insert.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

print("Files are imported in table!")

Python loads all the data correctly; it's just that some rows in the database are not in the same order as in Excel. They are loaded correctly but are not in the correct order in the database.
Any Ideas?
I have no idea what can be the reason for order change, because the data in Excel are well prepared.

The rows in a relational database table are not ordered. If you need them sorted, use an ORDER BY clause when selecting them.

I need them just in order they are in Excel, and are they not uploaded in the same order? Is there explanation in which order they upload data in database?

Order or records can be changed, for example, if SQL request contains OR operator in WHERE clause. It returns records groped by OR operands conditions. If nothing helps, you can enumerate records in Excel first, then request them sorted by this enumeration.

I added a row number from the Excel file into the database, sorted by that number, and then removed the column with the numbering.
Thank you!

That will not last, as soon as you do a data change to the table the 'order' will change. As has been pointed out already SQL data sets do not have a defined ordering. If you want to see the data in a given order you will need to use an ORDER BY.
